# Fill a form with saved cookies

Tags: java, jsp, cookies, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I have an action class that saves my cookies like this:

```java
public String execute() {

    // Save to cookie
      Cookie name = new Cookie("name", userInfo.getName() );
      name.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365); // Make the cookie last a year!
      servletResponse.addCookie(name);
}
```

If I submit my form, I can see the cookies on the browser that has been created and saved. When the user submits, they get redirected to a new page, a page with all the stored information that they just created.

I want the user to be able to go back to the submit page and see all the information in the forms that they just submitted. Is it possible to do this with Struts2, by using the saved Cookies and get the form to fill in with the old data?

This is my form:

```jsp
<s:textfield
        label="Name"
        name="name"
        key="name" 
        tooltip="Enter your Name here"/>
```

Comment: Do you want to fill form with the cookie data? How you are showing that data in your *new page* right now?

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes. I want to fill the form with the cookie data, so when the user goes back to that page, the info is there on the page. I show the data like this: <s:property value="name" />. Thanks for your response.

Comment: So right now you aren't using data from cookie at all, right? Take a look at cookie interceptor - http://struts.apache.org/docs/cookie-interceptor.html.

Comment: Exactly, I am not using the cookies data at all. I have looked at it before, tried to implement it, and it didn't work, and I'm not sure how to work with it. Do you have experience with cookie interceptor?

Comment: Post what have you tried with cookie interceptor and how it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @AleksandrM java.lang.NullPointerException at the line when the cookies are trying to get saved.

Comment: The code isn't showing when I try to edit it in my first post. But I added the interceptor in my package that is used for the form if that makes sense. And I'm not sure how to use it from there.

Comment: @JohnPulple You can send a cookie with the response if you can get access to it, but you should know that for this task isn't required to do so, if you can relay it on the framework.

Comment: @RomanC How would I do that Roman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send cookie you can use a [cookie-provider](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/cookie-provider-interceptor.html) interceptor. It allows you to populate cookies in the action via implementing `CookieProvider`. To apply this interceptor to the action configuration you can override the interceptors config

```xml
<action ... >
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="cookieProvider"/>
  ...
</action>
```

The `CookieProvider` has a method to implement,

```java
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements CookieProvider {

    @Override
    public Set<Cookie> getCookies(){
      Set<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<>();
      Cookie name = new Cookie("name", userInfo.getName() );
      name.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365); // Make the cookie last a year!
      name.setPath("/"); //Make it at root.
      cookies.add(name);
      return cookies;
    }

}
```

In the form

```jsp
<s:set var="name">${cookie["name"].value}</s:set>
<s:textfield
        label="Name"
        name="name"
        value="%{#name}"
        tooltip="Enter your Name here"/>
```

Comment: Hm, I think I'm not using the getCookies method correctly in my action class. How am I suppose to use it? Right now I just have it in my action class, exactly like you wrote it. Because I accidentally had my old code (like I'm showing in the OP, with the //save cookie in execute method), and now when I removed it, the cookie doesn't get saved anywhere.

Comment: It's used by the interceptor, cookies are stored at the root context, where you should probably deploy at runtime.

Comment: I'm deploying at the root context (Pretty sure at least). But I don't find the cookie in my browser now when I removed my old code that I had from the beginning in my execute method, so the cookie only was saved from that, and not by the interceptor.

Comment: The interceptor should apply at action config.

Comment: Now I get the Cookie again, I had forgotten to add the CookieProvider interface. And I see my cookie name where I implemented the <set var="name", but not where I set the value. So the name of the cookie is shown above the form. Thanks again for your time, I highly appreciate it Roman.

Comment: The value of input field should be populated with variable value `#name`, you can also try to print its value with `<s:property  value="#name"/>` after the set tag. If you have a cookie in the request then the variable should be initialized.

Comment: value="<s:property value="#name"/>" - Like this? Not sure what you mean with, "If you have a cookie in the request then the variable should be initialized." Could you please explain that?

Comment: You said that you see the cookie name in the `set` tag, where did you see it. The cookies are sent by the browser with the request. And you can use it to read a cookie `request.getCookies()`. And you can't use nested tags in attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69769/discussion-between-john-pulple-and-roman-c).

Comment: Hey Roman! Do you got time to help me again in the chat? If so, I would highly appreciate if you could visit me in the chatroom!