# Converting null to an empty String in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, cookies, struts2, jstl, ognl

I have a form in struts 2, that I show the value of a cookie like this:

```
 <s:set var="name">${cookie["name"].value}</s:set>
<s:textfield name="name" value="%{#name}"/>
```

But everytime the cookie is null (when the user first logs in), it isn't blank, but it is showing "javabrains.model.User@17030961". I want that value to be blank in my form. So I tried to use if tag in Struts2, so whenever the name is null, it is set to blank, like this:

```
<s:if test="#name == ''"><s:set var="name" value="''"/></s:if>
```

Now it works, I can see my form being blank when there is no cookie present, but I want it to show the cookie's value, so I tried to use an else tag to get the cookie value:

```
 <s:else><s:set var="name">${cookie["name"].value}</s:set> </s:else>
```

Now it doesn't work, because when the cookie is absent, it is still showing "javabrains.model.User@17030961".

Is there another solution that works better? To clarify I'm trying to make a form have blank values when there is no cookie present, and when there is a cookie, I want it to fill in that value.

Comment: That is why you need to use `cookie` interceptor.

Comment: @AleksandrM Should I not use CookieProvider, and instead use cookie interceptor? Thanks in advance.

Comment: They serve different purposes. See http://struts.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html#Interceptors-FrameworkInterceptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28199612/1654265) to another question of your. In this code:

```xml
<s:set var="name">${cookie["name"].value}</s:set>
<s:textfield name="name" value="%{#name}" />
```

`#name` is the `<s:set>` variable's name, **NOT the cookie name**. To make it clear:

```xml
<s:set var="foobar">${cookie["name"].value}</s:set>
<s:textfield name="name" value="%{#foobar}" />
```

Then, your attempt to check the cookie value OUTSIDE the `<s:set>` declaration is wrong, because you are trying to test the `<s:set>` variable instead (and before it is even created)!

You should check the cookie value with something like:

```xml
<s:if test="#cookie.name!=null">
    <s:set var="name">${cookie["name"].value}</s:set>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:set var="name" value="''"/>
</s:else>
```

, but since you are using only the CookieProvider interceptor, try using the ternary operator directly in JSP EL:

```xml
<s:set var="name">${not empty cookie["name"] ? cookie["name"].value : ''}</s:set>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but it keeps getting the same result whenever I want it be ' ' (empty). Strange thing is if I add a random letter inside of  ' ', like ' a ', it prints out a fine. Any idea why it is this way?

Comment: So the ternary is working but the `''` is the problem ? Try using `' '` with a space in the middle. But this makes no sense to me :)

Comment: I tried that too, still not working. Yeah seems very strange. Any other tips on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`<s:set var="name">${not empty cookie["name"] ? cookie["name"].value : "notfound"}</s:set>
<s:if test="#name== 'notfound'"><s:set var="name" value="''"/></s:if>`

After checking like this my form is working well,It will show the cookies value if cookies are available if not it will show the input box as empty